# how to adjust time for trips?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have some trips per each person and each household. the first 2 rows of data is like this

```
      Household      person       trip      are.time     depends.time    duration
         1              1           0        02:20:00        08:20:00    NA
         1              1           1        08:50:00        17:00:00    30
```

This means that the person start trip at 8:20 and get to destination at 8:50 . that's why duration is 30. (is trip duration)

Now I want to put start time of each trip in the same row as that trip.
like this

```
      Household      person       trip   start.time.    are.time      depends.time    duration
         1              1           0         NA.     02:20:00        08:20:00          NA
         1              1           1      08:20:00   08:50:00       17:00:00         30
```

Notice that for zero trip of each person we do not have start time so I put NA.

Comment: take a look into the lubridate package for a simple solution: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/vignettes/lubridate.html

Comment: @heck1 thanks, which part or function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution using `dplyr` with base R functions for time manipulation.

First create the data

```
df <- data.frame(
    Household = c(1, 1),
    person = c(1, 1),
    trip = c(0, 1),
    are.time = c("02:20:00", "08:50:00"),
    depends.time = c("08:20:00", "17:00:00"),
    duration = c(NA, 30)
)
```

Then subtract 30 minutes where `duration` is not `NA`. I multiply duration*60 here because `as.numeric(strptime())` is converting the string to a value in the units of seconds and we want to add duration*60 seconds to the value.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(start.time = case_when(
    !is.na(duration) ~ as.character(as.POSIXct(as.numeric(strptime(are.time, "%H:%M:%S")) - duration*60, origin="1970-01-01"), format="%H:%M:%S"),
    TRUE ~ NA_character_
  ))
```

Output:

```
  Household person trip are.time depends.time duration start.time
1         1      1    0 02:20:00     08:20:00       NA       <NA>
2         1      1    1 08:50:00     17:00:00       30   08:20:00
```

Comment: Creating the data is important to establish a minimum working example. If you already have data, that's fine, naturally you can skip that step assuming the data is similar to the data in the example.

Comment: Hah! My bad. See the updated answer. It's `duration*60`